# Wrong Javascript order: Undefined variable: jQuery

Tags: javascript

Since I moved all scripts form the header to the bottom of the page (in the template file of my theme) I have the problem that some scripts of contributed modules ([chosen](https://drupal.org/project/chosen) and device geolocation from [smart ip](https://drupal.org/project/smart_ip)) are added before the JQuery library. Using Jquery this leads to an error:

```
Undefined variable: jQuery
```

What can I do to get the right order and what could be the reason of the fact that the order is only wrong when the scripts are added at the bottom of the page and not in the header?

Comment: Realizing after I answered, the first question should be: how did you move all of the scripts? Did you just print `$scripts` in your footer?

Comment: @ChrisRockwell Yes, this is, what I did.

Answer (score 3):

Modules, via [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) can define the 'scope' and 'weight'. The 'scope' defaults to header, so unless you change this via `drupal_add_js()` in your template.php file, you can't move `print $scripts` from your header, or you'll have this problem with, likely, most contrib modules.

To change this, you could do something like this in `yourtheme_preprocess_page($vars)`:

```
$js = drupal_add_js();
$newJs = array()
foreach ($js as $s) {
  $s['scope'] = 'footer';
  $newJs = $s;
}

drupal_add_js($newJs);
```

Comment: As long as everything is following Drupal best practices for Javascript, I don't recall ever having a problem moving my `<?php print $scripts ?>` to the end of the body, but before `$page_bottom` in html.tpl.php.